# How to implement Multiple App components based on URL

Tags: reactjs

i need to create some kind of multi page app for my clients. Main goal is that, based on URL, i need to load a specific App.js file.

[image: my folder structure]

Then for example if user goes to localhost:3000/partner1 i need to include App.js from context/partner1 folder, etc.

In my index.js file i created a function:

```
const renderApp = () => {
  return (
    <App/>
  )
}
```

which is called below like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {renderApp()}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

how to refactor this code to load App component from specific catalog based on URL?

Comment: const routes = [
{'ParamName1': <ParamName1/>},
{'ParamName2': <ParamName2/>},
]
read params and check this static router array and
conditionally render. as you can see the names are there for you to match specified component in this array of objects

Comment: @emre-ozgun could you implement some snippet?

Comment: why not just import them in app.js and use regular routing via react-router meaning you just regularly render them ? are you forced to keep that folder structure untouched ? so your problem if I understand correctly, originates from the fact that you can't use the folder name to render ?